# Compare each row in a table to every other row, once and once only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table full of records which I would like to compare to every other record in the same table. Consider this table.

```
create table temp (rec char(1));
```

Populated with this data:

```
insert into temp (rec) values ('a');
insert into temp (rec) values ('b');
insert into temp (rec) values ('c');
insert into temp (rec) values ('d');
```

And queried with this SQL:

```
select a.rec, b.rec
from temp a, temp b
```

This returns 16 rows (as expected) but it includes extra rows where 'a' = 'a' and 'b' = 'b'. To remove these I can change the query to.

```
select a.rec, b.rec
from temp a, temp b 
where a.rec <> b.rec
```

This cuts the results down to 12 rows:

```
"a" - "b"
"a" - "c"
"a" - "d"
"b" - "a"
"b" - "c"
"b" - "d"
"c" - "a"
"c" - "b"
"c" - "d"
"d" - "a"
"d" - "b"
"d" - "c"
```

However, it still pulls back some duplicates, not only does it pull back a record where 'a' = 'b' but it also pulls back 'b' = 'a' which I have no interest in (I've already compared record 'a' with record 'b' so have no interest in doing the same comparison the other way around)

So, how can I alter the query to compare every row with every other row once and once only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use distinct with your last query:

```
select distinct least(a.rec, b.rec), greatest(a.rec, b.rec)
from temp a
  cross join temp b 
where a.rec <> b.rec;
```

The expression `least(a.rec, b.rec), greatest(a.rec, b.rec)` turns `b,a` into `a,b` and the `distinct` then removes the duplicates.

Online example: https://rextester.com/TDZQ5153

Comment: Thanks horse_with_no_name - this is really useful for me. My live query actually contains 10s of thousands of rows of data which results in 100s of millions of results. Your solution cuts this down massively and greatly reduces processing time.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your condition to `<`:

```
select a.rec, b.rec
from temp a join
     temp b 
     on a.rec < b.rec;
```